# No errors but no audio?

Tags: java, audio, netbeans

I put this right after I listed my imports, there are no errors but when I click run my interface shows up but there is no audio. I have the .wav file in the src directory and I've placed it in every folder once but still when I click run there is no audio. Assistance would be very appreciated.

```
public class Mygame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private Clip music;
private void startSong(){
    try{
        AudioInputStream stream =               AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("gamemusic.wav"));
        music = AudioSystem.getClip();
        music.open(stream);
        music.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e){

        music = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: never ignore exceptions. no wonder you do not see any error

Comment: How can you tell if exception was thrown or not? Print the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

If you are using netbeans then paste your wav file in Files tab beside project tab at left top corner.

Comment: I did, no music still though.